# Matching 2 fingerprints in Android SDK

Tags: gracenote

Is there any way to know if 2 fingerprints(fingerprinted by gracenote sdk for android)  refer to same song without using gracenote servers.

I'm only interested in comparing fingerprints, not the meta data of song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracenote does not currently offer any fingerprint comparison functionality in its SDKs or APIs. Our fingerprinting service is designed to identify and provide metadata for a given audio recording/file in our database, and not to compare two arbitrary fingerprints.